# How do you pass a List_File_Path to an Azure Data Factory U-SQL activity?

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

[Input Files (U-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/concepts/files/input-files) states that input paths can take any of the following forms:

```
Input_File_Path :=                                                                                       
     Single_File_Path 
|    List_File_Path 
|    File_Set_Path.
```

As an example of List_File_Path they provide:

```
@searchLog =  
    EXTRACT UserId          int  
          , Start           DateTime  
          , Region          string  
          , Query           string  
          , Duration        int  
          , Urls            string  
          , ClickedUrls     string
    FROM "/Samples/Outputs/ExampleA.csv",
         "/Samples/Outputs/ExampleB.csv"
    USING Extractors.Csv();
```

I have the following code:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL @FileList string = "ListOfFiles.txt";
@searchLog =  
    EXTRACT UserId          int  
          , Start           DateTime  
          , Region          string  
          , Query           string  
          , Duration        int  
          , Urls            string  
          , ClickedUrls     string
    FROM @FileList
    USING Extractors.Csv();
```

If I pass in the parameter FileList as `@variables('FileList')` where FileList is an array, I get the following error:

```
Error Id: E_STORE_USER_FAILURE_83090017, Error Message: Invalid pathname Cosmos Path:
```

It is treating FileList as if it were: `"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]"`

If I pass in the parameter FileList as `@join(variables('FileList'),',')` If treats FileList as if it were: `"Dir/File1.txt,Dir/File2.txt"` That is, as if it is a single file name.

I also tried using `@join(variables('FileList'),',')` with this:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL @FileList string = "ListOfFiles.txt";
@searchLog =  
    EXTRACT UserId          int  
          , Start           DateTime  
          , Region          string  
          , Query           string  
          , Duration        int  
          , Urls            string  
          , ClickedUrls     string
    FROM @FileList.Split(',')
    USING Extractors.Csv();
```

But that generates the following error: `C# error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string[]' to 'string'`

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

U-SQL:

```
DECLARE EXTERNAL @FileList1 string = "ListOfFiles.txt";
DECLARE EXTERNAL @FileList2 string = "ListOfFiles.txt";

@searchLog =  
    EXTRACT UserId          int  
          , Start           DateTime  
          , Region          string  
          , Query           string  
          , Duration        int  
          , Urls            string  
          , ClickedUrls     string
    FROM @FileList1,@FileList2
    USING Extractors.Csv();

OUTPUT @searchLog
TO "/output/exampleD.csv" 
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

parameters:
[image]

Comment: I ended up with a solution like this. However, it is really deficient as it doesn't allow for variations in the number of files (I can have between 1 and 3 files). I ended up creating a number of placeholder files to pass in when I had less than the maximum number of files. It should also be noted that you can't have the same filename more than once.